# $f(x)=(x-1)^b\ln(x)$, what is the $(b+1)^{th}$ derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

If $f(x)=(x-1)^b\ln(x)$, $b \in \mathbb{N}$, does $f^{(b+1)}(1)=(b+1)$? That is, the $(b+1)^{th}$ derivative of the function f, at x=1. I was prompted in another question to compute the power series of this function. Another way is to use taylor series and sort of "brute force" it by trying different values of b.

For the power series representation, I'm thinking of using the series $(1+x)^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)..(n-k+1)}{k!}$, where I substitute b for n. Is this a viable option?

On the other hand, I tried some values of b with the taylor series. I chose $b=1, 2, 4, 5$ and $f^{(b+1)}(1)=(b+1)$ is true for each of these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power series of $f$ at $x = 1$ is equal to the power series of $g(x) = f(x+1) = x^b \log (x+1)$ at $x = 0$.  Since the expansion of $g$ is simply $$g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} x^{k+b}$$ it immediately follows that the expansion of $f$ at $x = 1$ is $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} (x-1)^{k+b} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k+b)!}{k} \frac{(x-1)^{k+b}}{(k+b)!}$$ and $$f^{(b+1)}(1) = \left[\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k+b)!}{k}\right]_{k=1} = (b+1)!.$$

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat more generally: if $A_1, \ldots, A_m$ are all $m$ times differentiable in a neighbourhood of $x=1$ and $A_1(1), \ldots, A_m(1)$ are all $0$, then $$ \left.\dfrac{d^m}{dx^m} (A_1(x) \ldots A_m(x))\right|_{x=1}
= m!\; A_1'(1) \ldots A_m'(1)$$
The point is that the left side is a sum of terms, each of which is $0$ at $x=1$ unless each of the $A_k$ has been differentiated.